# List values being added to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary, but it keeps splitting the string `"10"` as `"1"` and `"0"`. How do I fix this?

```py
suits = ['h', 'd', 's', 'c']
values = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
cards = {"h" : [], 'd': [], 's': [], 'c': []}

for suit in cards:
    for value in values:
        cards[suit] += value

print(cards)
```

output:

```
{'h': ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '1', '0', 'J', 'Q', 'K'], 'd': ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '1', '0', 'J', 'Q', 'K'], 's': ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '1', '0', 'J', 'Q', 'K'], 'c': ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '1', '0', 'J', 'Q', 'K']}
```

How do I stop the value 10 from being split as 1 and 0?

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix to your code is to change:

```py
cards[suit] += value
```

to:

```py
cards[suit].append(value)
```

Remember, you can put any iterable (not just list) into the right hand side of the list's `+=` operator. It basically iterates through that iterable and append them to the original list:

```py
lst = []
lst += "10"
print(lst)   # ['1', '0']
```

You don't want this "extending" behavior, so `.append()` the item instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is it:

```
suits = ['h', 'd', 's', 'c']
values = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
cards = {}

for suit in suits:
    for value in values:
        if suit not in cards.keys(): 
            a=[]
            a.append(value)
            cards[suit]=a
        else:
            cards[suit].append(value)
        
print(cards)
```

output:

```
{'h': ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K'], 
'd': ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K'], 
's': ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K'], 
'c': ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']}
```